# blank page after titlingpage

Tags: memoir, titles, blank-page

I'm using memoir, and I just want to delete the blank page after the title, do anyone know how to do that?

my code:

```
    \documentclass[openany,12pt]{memoir}
\chapterstyle{section}

\setlength\afterchapskip {\onelineskip }
\setlength\beforechapskip {\onelineskip }

%ligando a numeração da subsection
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
\maxtocdepth{subsubsection}

%alterando nome da tabela e da figura
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura: }
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabela: }

%Margem
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.3cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.3cm}

%fazendo os headers e footers
\makepagestyle{plainstyle}
\makeevenhead{plainstyle}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{plainstyle}{}{}{} 

\makeevenfoot{plainstyle}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{plainstyle}{}{\thepage}{}

\pagestyle{plainstyle}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{plainstyle}

%tamanho que o texto ocupa
%\textwidth=16cm
%\setlength{\voffset}{-0.6in}
%\setlength{\textheight}{600pt}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{lipsum}
%para tabelas grandes
\usepackage{longtable}

%para colocar um width maximo para as figuras do comando
%[max width = ...]
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

%packages inseridos que não são do estilo.

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{morefloats}

%Tirando hifenização(???)
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000


\begin{document}
%incluindo a capa.      
\begin{titlingpage}
\input{capa/capa}

\input{agradecimentos/agradecimentos}

\input{resumo/resumo}
\end{titlingpage}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sumário}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\renewcommand*\listfigurename{Lista de figuras}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\renewcommand*\listtablename{Lista de Tabelas}
%\listoftables

\renewcommand\bibname{Referências bibliográficas}

%inclusão das seções

%%INTRODUÇÂO
\input{introducao/introducao}
%%REVISAO BIBLIOGRAFICA
\input{revisaoteorica/revisaoteorica}
%%METODOLOGIA
\input{metodologia/metodologia}

%%RESULTADOS E DISCUSSÕES
\input{resultadosediscussoes/resultadosediscussoes}
%% CONCLUSÃO
\input{conclusao/conclusao}
%%Referencias bibliograficas
\input{referenciasbibliograficas/referenciasbibliograficas}



\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please complete your code to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 5):

Discard the page during shipout using

```
\usepackage{atbegshi}
%...
\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}
\begin{titlingpage}
  % <title content>
\end{titlingpage}
```

We delay this discarding until the second page using a nested `\AtBeginShipoutNext`.

Comment: What effects does this have on odd/even recto/verso page numbering and can it be mitigated?

Comment: @svenper: Page numbering is not affected as the page is discarded just before shipout. The presentation within a reader might change, but that's because it makes some assumption on the layout based on the page numbers. For example, Adobe Reader won't skip a page in the layout presentation if you remove some page mid-document (if I recall).

Comment: @Werner, thank you very much for this fix!